# Importing .txt data into R

Tags: r, file, read.table

I'm trying to import a text file into R which has several columns separated by `|`. Here is the first line:

C00088591|N|M3|P|15970306895|15|IND|BURCH, MARY K.|FALLS CHURCH|VA|220424511|NORTHROP GRUMMAN|VP PROGRAM MANAGEMENT|02132015|500||2A8EE0688413416FA735|998834|||4032020151240885624

I used `read.table` to read the data:

`pc <- read.table(file = source(file.choose()), header = FALSE, sep = "|")`

However I get this error message when I execute the code above:

`Error in source(file.choose()) :  /Users/na/Desktop/Thesis/04_Data/Campaign contributions/indiv16/by_date/itcont_2016_10151005_20150726.txt:1:42: unexpected ',' 1: C00088591|N|M3|P|15970306895|15|IND|BURCH, ^`

I went ahead and erased the commas in the dataset but it didn't work either:

`Error in source(file.choose()) :  /Users/na/Desktop/itcont_2016_10151005_20150726 copy.txt:1:43: unexpected symbol 1: C00088591|N|M3|P|15970306895|15|IND|BURCH MARY ^`

Is it because there are multiple words in a column? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `source` function call, it doesn’t fit here (the function does something completely different).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of the second error, and even if you resolve it, there could still be problems.  Assuming you expect each pipe-separated line to only contain pipes or alphanumeric characters, you could use the following regex to flag problematic rows:

```regex
^.*[^A-Za-z0-9|].*$
```

You may use any text editor or tool with basic regex support.